# Parse latest change to folder SVN with Python

Tags: python, svn, awk, sed, directory

I have a folder structure in a Subversion Repo as follows:

```
tags/
  +--> 0/
   +--> file.txt
  +--> 1/
   +--> file.txt
  +--> 2/
   +--> file.txt
```

I want to associate the folder names 0, 1, 2 ... with the latest change to a file within that folder. So, for example a dict `{'0': dt(2014,23,2), '1': dt(2013,1,2), '2': dt(2016,1,1)}`.

What you can do is use `svn log url/.../tags/x/` on each `svn ls url/.../tags/` and get something like

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1815234 | user | 2013-11-05 10:53:25 +0000 (Tue, 05 Nov 2013) | 1 line

comment
------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

and use a awk, sed combo on that.

```
svn log http://url/tags/0/ | awk 'NR==2 {print $5; print $6}'
```

Any ideas for a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
import os
import datetime

dict_final = {}
for elt in os.listdir('./tags'):
    if os.path.isdir(elt):
        # dict that compiles all filenames with last changes date
        files_stats = {filename: os.stat(os.path.join(elt, filename)).st_mtime
                       for filename in os.listdir(elt)}
        # Extract file changed last
        filename, last_changes = max(files_stats.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
        dict_final.update({elt: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(last_changes)})

print dict_final
```